# How to show $f_n $ converges to $f$ weakly

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

$1<p< \infty$

$f_n\in L^p[a,b] $ is bounded sequnce $f\in L^p[a,b]$ such that

$\int_K f_n(t)\to \int _K f$

for all measurable set $K$ in $[a,b]$  Then we have to prove that $f_n \to f$ weakly

My attempt We know that dual of $L^p[a,b] $ is $L^q[a,b] $ where $\frac1p+ \frac1q=1$

SO we have to show that $\int f_n g\to \int fg$

By Holders inequality $\lvert \int f_ng-fg \rvert <||f_n-f||_p||g||_q$

AS we are in compact set $L^1$ converges implies $L^p$ converges But how to prove $L^1$ converges

we only have $\int_K f_n(t)\to \int _K f$

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What space does $g$ live in?

Comment: g lives in L^q dual space of Lp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holder's inequality won't help you with $f_n - f$ because you don't know whether $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$. 
The additivity of the integral is enough to get you that
$$\int f_n \phi \to \int f\phi$$ for every simple function $\phi$. Now, if $g \in L^q$, $1 < q < \infty$, then for any simple function $\phi$ you have 
$$ \left| \int f g - \int f_n g \right| \le \int |f||g - \phi| + \int |f_n| |g - \phi| + \left| \int f \phi - \int f_n \phi \right|.$$

Apply Holder's inequality here (and use the fact that a weakly convergent sequence in $L^p$ is norm bounded) to obtain a constant $M$ with the property that 
$$\limsup_m \left| \int f g - \int f_n g \right| \le M \|g-\phi\|_q.$$ The right hand side can be made arbitrarily small using the density of simple functions in $L^q$.